# How to fix : Type 'Window' is not assignable to type 'typeof globalThis'

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I am trying an angular project from github. I am using node version 12, angular cli 9, and updated package.json.

https://github.com/chat21/chat21-web-widget
From these two files, I am getting an error while building.
https://github.com/chat21/chat21-web-widget/blob/master/src/app/providers/translator.service.ts
https://github.com/chat21/chat21-web-widget/blob/master/src/app/utils/globals.tsLine 31

```
let windowContext = window;
if (window.frameElement && window.frameElement.getAttribute('tiledesk_context') === 'parent') {
  windowContext = window.parent;
}
```

Error Type: 'Window' is not assignable to type 'typeof globalThis'.

windowContext = window.parent;

I think this is the problem related to typescript but I am not familiar with that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this error is expected. When you created the **windowContext** variable,  You did not state a type, so typescript inferred that **windowContext** is of type *"Window & typeof globalThis"*.

Then you tried to reassign the variable, but you reassigned it with a different type. **window.parent** is of type "*Window*". So the types don't match.

you can try this

```
    let windowContext: any = window;
     if (window.frameElement && 
      window.frameElement.getAttribute('tiledesk_context') === 'parent') {
       windowContext = window.parent;
     }
```

Comment: Thanks, I had previously tried after googling with     let windowContext = <any> window; and it worked fine. Is it good to use for practice or the one you suggested? Nay differences in both ?

Comment: I think its a matter of what you prefer